# gulp-less fails when using !important

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, less

When we use !important on a specific less variable, the build fails. We use !important all over the place and I have no idea what makes this one any different.

Setup:

customer1.less

```
@import "basefile";

@wrapper-height: auto !important;
...
```

basefile.less

```
@import 'variables/basefile-variables';
...
```

basefile-variables.less

```
@wrapper-height: auto;
...
```

Error when running gulp-less:

```
Error in plugin "gulp-less"
Message:
    Cannot create property '_index' on string '!important' in file /<redacted>/customer1.less line no. 1
Details:
    type: Syntax
    filename: /<redacted>/customer1.less
    index: NaN
    line: 1
    column: -1
    callLine: NaN
    callExtract: undefined
    extract: ,@import "basefile";,
    lineNumber: 1
    fileName: /<redacted>/customer1.less
```

Comment: I had a similar issue today where compilation failed on a particular machine with the same message. In this case, removing the "!important" properties from the two places it was found in the offending file solved it. gulp-less 4.0.1.

Comment: @swalladge yea this is what we ended up doing but there must be some kind of bug in gulp-less.

Answer (score -1):

It could be that your variable `@wrapper-height` is hyphenated.

Try a var name like `@wrapperHeight` and see how Gulp handles that.

UPDATED:
Actually, you're trying to import `basefile` instead of `basefile.less` - try adding the .less file extension.

Comment: Nah, we have hyphenated variables all over and it has not been an issue previously. You don't need to add .less to the imports, it works fine without them.